# multiprocessing iterator, filter what gets added to the deque

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, deque

I am running a large comparison, but approximately 25% of the total run time is spent cleaning the deque after the comparisons are complete. My code looks something like this:

```
from collections import deque
from multiprocessing import Pool
from _map_workflow import val_comp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    records = deque(pool.imap_unordered(val_comp, combinations(index_tups,2)))

    for _ in range(records.count(None)):
        records.remove(None)
```

The comparison function `val_comp` only returns values if certain criteria are met, but the deque gets loaded with `None` when nothing is returned. Since I'm the multiprocessing is using `imap` I am unsure how to filter what is getting added to the deque.

Is there a faster/more efficient way to remove these `None`'s or prevent them from be adding in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.remove` is [an O(N) operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for `deque` objects.

So, overall, if there are M None's, you have O(M*N) behavior.

This is totally avoidable. One simple way is to use `filter`:

```
records = deque(filter(None, pool.imap_unordered(val_comp, combinations(index_tups,2))))
```

If you wanted to filter them out after you already have your `records` deque, you could do something like:

```
records = deque(x for x in records if x is not None)
```

Which creates a new `deque`.

Comment: This is great. Now I get why it was so slow, thanks!